# Beautifulsoup AJAX table to JSON

Tags: json, ajax, beautifulsoup, html-table

Attempting to scrape data from a table from a page. However it has an AJAX call to reveal everything on the table. Below is my code but I come to this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Can anyone give some insight as to how I am able to get this data?

```
url_link = requests.get(URL)
file = bs.BeautifulSoup(url_link.text, "lxml")
          
find_table = file.find('table', id_='viewAllSeriesTable')
rows = find_table.find_all('td')

with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
            for i in rows:
                table_data = i.find_all('td')
                data = [j.text for j in table_data]
                json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: <table width="735" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" border="0" id="viewAllSeriesTable">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th id="id">Series ID</th>
    <th id="seriesName">Series Name</th>
    <th id="clientName">Client Name</th>
    <th id="Brand">Brand</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody><tr><td id="9127" style="word-break: break-word;"><a href="seriesDefinition.html?id=9127">9127</a></td><td style="word-break: break-word;">a</td><td style="word-break: break-word;">A</td><td style="word-break: break-word;">B</td></tr>

Comment: I don't have a public URL but this is the table

Comment: If you `print(find_table)` what's the ouptut? does it find the correct tags? or is the output `None`?
Also, does the table appear in `print(file.prettify())` ?

Answer (score 1):

When your looking for the table by it's ID with:

```
find_table = file.find('table', id_='viewAllSeriesTable')
```

Don't pass `id_=` as an argument, instead, use `id=` without the underscore:

```
find_table = file.find("table", id="viewAllSeriesTable")
```

Also, you have already found all `<td>` with:

```
rows = find_table.find_all('td')
```

so don't iterate over it again to find the `td` with:

```
for i in rows:
    table_data = i.find_all('td')
```

---

Here's a working example:

```
file = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

find_table = file.find("table", id="viewAllSeriesTable")
rows = find_table.select("td")

with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    data = [j.get_text(strip=True) for j in rows]
    json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Creates a file `data_file.json` containing:

```
["9127", "a", "A", "B"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Though I am getting an error for select
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to get the source rather than the direct link because it requires authentication
        source = driver.page_source
Thanks for your help, appreciated

Comment: @user15708120 Thought so, I was using the provided HTML as an example

Comment: What would be the way to store each td under its th?